# SQL One to many join - do not return rows from the 'one' table if ANY row in the 'many' table equals X

Tags: sql, join

I have tried searching for this question but have had some trouble describing it.

I have two tables, `order_items` and `processes` in a one to many relationship. There can be many processes for a single order item. I wish to select rows from `order_items` where no corresponding row in `processes` equals a number, say 1, 2 or 3. I would still like to return the rows in `order_items` if there is no corresponding rows in `processes`, ie null values.

As an example

```
`order_items`
item_number     order_value
    1               10
    2               20
    3               10


`processes`
item_number    process_number
    1               1
    1               4
    2               4
    2               5
```

The query I wish to make would not return item_number 1 as it has process_number in (1, 2, 3) but would return item number 2 and 3.

```
Results
item_number    order_value
    2              20
    3              10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM order_items o
WHERE item_number NOT IN (
    SELECT item_number
    FROM processes
    WHERE process_number IN (1, 2, 3)
    )
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a8658/6)</kbd>